# Qt c++ let ListWidget Icon pull out to local using cursor

Tags: c++, qt, cursor

In My widget this picture, i have two icon, how can i pull them to local file by cursor to pull them using qt c++. Drag and drop can't set to local container!

[My Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knLVf.png)

Comment: Do you mean you want to drag the icon in the Qt program, then drop it outside of the program (to desktop, or to explorer, etc.) ?

Comment: post your image within your question please

Comment: yap , you got me!

Comment: Benjamin , you can see in My widget this hyperlinks, my question is just like  TheSHEEEP said.